# Adding number to pointer value

Tags: c++, pointer-arithmetic

I am trying to add a number to a  pointer value with the following expression:

```
&AddressHelper::getInstance().GetBaseAddress() + 0x39EA0;
```

The value for the `&AddressHelper::getInstance().GetBaseAddress()` is always `0x00007ff851cd3c68 {140700810412032}`

should I not get `0x00007ff851cd3c68 + 0x39EA0 = 7FF81350DB08` as a result?

while I am getting: `0x00007ff851ea3168` or sometimes `0x00007ff852933168` or some other numbers.

Did I took the pointer value incorrectly?

Comment: Pointer arithmetic take into account **type** of the pointer...

Comment: You're trying to add to the address of wherever base address is stored instead of adding to base address, trivial operator precedence. `&(AddressHelper::getInstance().GetBaseAddress() + 0x39EA0); `

Comment: Other point, pointer arithmetic have pedantically some restrictions (should be done in the "array range"). I suspect you would have UB.

Comment: So ignoring above UB, you certainly want (`static_cast<std::byte>(&AddressHelper::getInstance().GetBaseAddress()) + 0x39EA0`)

Comment: Adding hex values is no different than adding decimal values: the *representation* differs, but the *value* is the same. What you’re seeing is therefore unrelated to hexadecimal vs. decimal. It’s because of pointer arithmetic.

Comment: `(0x00007ff851ea3168 - 0x00007ff851cd3c68) / 0x39EA0 =
0x08`, So I suspect it is the size of your struct/type.

Comment: @Jarod42 would be nice if you provided exact source for that because there's no reason why following a pointer via an offset would be undefined behaviour in a specific case, such as remote process on AAMD64 under WindowsNT. Judging from the address size alone, it would be disingenuous to imply that this code will ever be compiled for an obscure microcontroller where this might be UB due to various reasons of how they may or may not handle pointers.

Comment: @Jarod42 the original variable was DWORD_PTR* type. I.e. 
`DWORD_PTR* address = &AddressHelper::getInstance().GetBaseAddress() + 0x39EA0;`

Comment: @Kaihaku: See [Pointer_arithmetic](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_arithmetic#Pointer_arithmetic). it is pedantically UB, even if it might works in practice for most compiler.

Comment: @Kaihaku The *standard* decides what is and isn’t UB. Saying that something is “UB on an obscure microcontroller” doesn’t make sense.

Comment: @Jarod42 that's for memory allocated by the process itself, which is naturally going to be a block of memory that can be indexed in some way using pointer arithmetic. What about arbitrary adresses? Besides, what they're trying to do is adding two integers and casting to a pointer, whether that pointer is valid is up to them. Common thing done with code injection. Most common use case is some sort of hack, or malware. Rarely used to patch up very old proprietary software as a last resort. If all these people are doing it wrong, why does it work?

Comment: @Kaihaku it is a hook, but not for the malware since we are discussing the moral justification behind this. In fact it is done with the hook specifically not to change the original in any shape or form.

Comment: **Pedantically**, you cannot have/use arbitrary adresses. Then compiler might decide what to do for some UB, but it is no longer inside C++ rules. Platform might provide "buffer" at specific address. Notice also that some compilers remove code which leads to UB.

Comment: @Jarod42 **pedantically** RAM is a huge array subdivided into smaller arrays which we call processes which as far as I know are linear arrays aswell, they may or may not be split up and nonsequential, but as long as you know the ranges, why is it UB to index into them if you know the base address, the address of byte array, containing all the bytes of the part of the process that you're interested in?

Comment: @Kaihaku: Pedantically, for C++, there is no RAM, stack, heap, register...

Comment: @Jarod42 C++ is a programming language and for a language that has terms such as `stack unwinding` right in its standard to have no notion of a stack would be problematic, to say the least. But what's your point? C++ does not have to know what kind of memory its operating on, that includes remote memory of some other process, its a block of memory, virtually mapped, like any other, where does UB come from if said memory is an array like any other? Does C++ standard specify somewhere that processes are not arrays?

Comment: @Kaihaku: using `constexpr` to detect UB, clang spots the "issue" (whereas we know there is a `int` in that memory) [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/W75ds37j3). There are rules. and some might be broken without noticing (In my country, I don't know any pedestrian who received a traffic ticket when crossing at red, but lot of people cross the road at red).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With pointer arithmetic, type is taken into account,

so with:

```
int buffer[42];
char* start_c = reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer);
int *start_i = buffer;
```

we have

- `start_i + 1 == &buffer[1]`
- `reinterpret_cast<char*>(start_i + 1) == start_c + sizeof(int)`.
- and (when `sizeof(int) != 1`) `reinterpret_cast<char*>(start_i + 1) != start_c + 1`

In your case:

```
0x00007ff851ea3168 - 0x00007ff851cd3c68) / 0x39EA0 = 0x08
```

and `sizeof(DWORD) == 8`.